# Unable to launch Project.app file through terminal

Tags: ios

I need to submit my iOS  simulator build to Facebook for review for Permissions approval. I generated the Project.app file using the steps listed in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced.

But the simulator command iso-sim launch path-to-app.app returns error:

> An error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159): Invalid device
>   state An error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159): Invalid device
>   state ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/User/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/6AFDE8D9-D331-4A8C-A05D-E7DFF4027C24/system.log'